# select statement error

Tags: php, oracle, select, pdo

I try the following code:

```
$data = $this->_db->select()->from(´IncidentInformation´,array(´IncidentID´,´ContactName´))->where("ContactName=?",$numAlert);
$result = $this->_db->fetchAll($data);
return $result;
```

But I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 904 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00904:
>   "CONTACTPHONE": invalid identifier (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:146)

Comment: Any chance you can debug the SQL statement that was used?

Comment: What are the terrible quotes?

Comment: Your tick marks (`) should not be used around string values.  Is that the actual code?

Comment: What is the value of `$numAlert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$data = $this->_db->select()->from('IncidentInformation',array('IncidentID','ContactName'))->where("ContactName=?",$numAlert);
$result = $this->_db->fetchAll($data);
return $result;
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 904 OCIStmtExecute: ORA-00904: "CONTACTPHONE": invalid identifier (ext\pdo_oci\oci_statement.c:146)

Comment: Number Phone for example : 990593431

Comment: Please Helppppppppppppppppp